# Unique attributes for certain data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse last post date from [this page](http://try.discourse.org/users/discoursetestr1/activity) using Beautiful soup, which says **3 days** (selected string). So far I tried:

```
lastPost = soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'dt': 'Last post', 'data-format': 'medium'})
```

but no success. All other tags and attributes are the same for other items in the page. Also

```
data-time="random digits"
```

not gonna work, because its different for the same item in different page/different user, which will be parsed lately. The only repetitive and unique is the Last post.
What could be the exact pointers to retrieve last post date (which is 3 days, as of posting this)?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why are you looking for `<dl>` elements when your highlight shows a *`<span>`* element?

Comment: Because `Last post` is out of `<span>` tags. That is the only unique attribute under which the last post date is located.

Comment: `find_all()` selects on **attributes** of individual tags, not on other tags.

Comment: Can you provide us with the raw HTML or a link to that page? It'll be a lot easier to build a demo with actual HTML to work with.

Comment: The data in that page is loaded by JavaScript, the data is not available in the page source as loaded from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `<span>` class here. I'd use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to pick it out:

```
soup.select('div.secondary dd span.relative-date')[0].string
```

If you specifically wanted to find the `<dt>Last Post</dt>` element and find your date relative to that, you'll need to first search for that element separately:

```
import re

last_post = soup.find('dt', text=re.compile('Last Post'))
last_post.find_next_sibling('dd').span.string
```

Note that `find_all()` filters *individual tags*; the `attrs={'dt': 'Last post', 'data-format': 'medium'}` filter means: find me a tag that has at least two attributes, `dt="Last post"` and `data-format="medium"`; the tag you are looking for does not have a `dt` attribute. This is apart from the fact that it is a `<span>` tag, not a `<dl>` tag.

That all said, the actual page doesn't actually contain the messages in HTML. Instead, those are loaded via AJAX; the page loads `http://try.discourse.org/user_actions.json?offset=0&username=discoursetestr1`, which contains the actual messages:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://try.discourse.org/user_actions.json?offset=0&username=discoursetestr1')
>>> r.json()['user_actions'][0]
{u'post_number': 4, u'target_name': u'discourse', u'excerpt': u'test........ \n\n \n\nlkjlkjlkljlkj', u'uploaded_avatar_id': 319, u'target_username': u'discoursetestR1', u'user_id': 4489, u'title': u'My custom own topic', u'moderator_action': False, u'acting_user_id': 4489, u'acting_name': u'E Mosbat', u'topic_id': 279, u'hidden': False, u'username': u'eMosbat', u'acting_uploaded_avatar_id': 319, u'deleted': False, u'acting_avatar_template': u'/user_avatar/try.discourse.org/emosbat/{size}/319.png', u'slug': u'my-custom-own-topic', u'avatar_template': u'/user_avatar/try.discourse.org/emosbat/{size}/319.png', u'name': u'E Mosbat', u'created_at': u'2014-05-27T13:25:49.988Z', u'target_user_id': 4481, u'action_type': 9, u'acting_username': u'eMosbat', u'category_id': 2}
 >>> r.json()['user_actions'][0]['created_at']
 u'2014-05-27T13:25:49.988Z'
```

Presumably the page JavaScript then produces a relative date from that information.

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot for the clarification. I wonder which other scraper/parser could do the job there?

Comment: @ikechi: Either simulate a full-blown browser (e.g. ghost.py or Selenium) and have the JavaScript executed for you, or load the AJAX requests directly.